# How to print individual elements of an "int[]" using a Stream in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, printing, java-stream

```
    int[] a = {10, 20, 30, 40};
    Stream.of(a).forEach(System.out::println);
```

for this code, i'm expecting the output (the values): 10 20 30 40 
But it is printing (the reference): [I@6d86b085

Am I missing anything (or) any changes in the Streams?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways you *could* do this. For example, you could change `Stream.of` to `IntStream.of` like

```
IntStream.of(a).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or, you could apply a `flatMap` to the `Stream.of` like

```
Stream.of(a).flatMap(x -> IntStream.of(x).boxed()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or, you could use `Arrays.stream` like

```
Arrays.stream(a).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I would recommend the first or the third, but I included the second to demonstrate that you can make it work with an `int[]` (just remember an `int[]` is an `Object`).

Comment: Thank you Elliott. Your first and thrid options are more useful than my own solution (changing the int[] to Integer[]). Thanks for introducing the IntStream to me. I have been around it but never used it.

Comment: But probably, there’s no need to have each value in a new line. Then, a plain `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));` would do. By the way, instead of `flatMap(x -> IntStream.of(x).boxed())`, I’d rather use `flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)`

Answer (score 0):

Following are some ways to print the elements in one line like `[10, 20, 30, 40]` using a `Stream`, instead of printing each element on a new line.

1. Using `Instream.of` to create an `IntStream` , `IntSream.mapToObj` to create stream of `String` representation of the elements.

Finally collecting to a List using `Stream.collect`. We will use the fact that printing `List` is done in the required format :

```
System.out.println( IntStream.of(minSquaresSumArr)
                      .mapToObj(x -> String.valueOf(x))
                      .collect( Collectors.toList() ) ) ;
```

or alternatively with `Arrays.stream()`

```
System.out.println( Arrays.stream(minSquaresSumArr)
                      .mapToObj(x -> String.valueOf(x))
                      .collect( Collectors.toList() )) ;
```

We can also convert `IntStream` to `Stream` of `Integer` first, and use `Integer.toSring` to convert that to a `Stream` of `String`

```
System.out.println( IntStream.of(minSquaresSumArr)
                      .boxed()
                      .map(x -> x.toString())
                      .collect( Collectors.joining(",") ) ) ;
```

2. Using the `IntStream.collect` method instead of `Stream.collect` to create the final string . Output is `10 20 30 40`

```
System.out.println( IntStream.of(minSquaresSumArr)
                      .collect( StringBuilder::new,
                          (x, y) -> { x.append(" ").append(y); return; },
                          (x, y) -> { x.append(" ").append(y); return; } )
                      .toString()) ;
```

Though if you just want to print the array, Holger's comment to use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));` is the simplest way to achieve that.

Answer (score -1):

Oh my bad, I have taken an int array instead of Integer array. The following code works fine.

```
Integer[] a = {10, 20, 30, 40};
Stream.of(a).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This solves a different problem to the one that you stated in your question!   (Sure ... your mistake was trying to solve the "wrong problem" ... but you asked a valid question, and it can be answered.)